# Modify entity framework mappings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapping

I had a column in a table which type was `nvarchar(50)` and had entity framework to generate te mappings and the model from that table for an asp mvc project, but after tricky error i found that the 50-length was to short for the type of field. I already modified the column to `nvarchar(100)` and on the mappings folder the Table.cs file has a line `this.Property(t => t.AColumn).HasMaxLength(50)`, i can guess that modifing the value to 100 should do the work, so is this all what i need or do i need Entity Framework to re-do everything, another question is how to make Razor, Entity or any tool to show some kind of message related to the mappings constrains.

**Edit:**

The error was that `AColumn` was too short for a form field but it didn't show a error message, it just shows errors from the model attributes or type constrains but not things defined on the mappings like `HasMaxLength(50)`, i want to be able to show the length error on the view if possible. The app just failed with an EntityFramework exception with a rather complicated traceback.

Thanks.

Comment: what mapping constraint message you want to show  ? on what event ?

Comment: Punctuation and paragraphs are great. Use them.